# Pandas Rolling Operation on Categorical column

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, object, rolling-computation

#### The code I am trying to execute:

```py
for cat_name in df['movement_state'].cat.categories:
    transformed_df[f'{cat_name} Count'] = grouped_df['movement_state'].rolling(rolling_window_size, closed='both').apply(lambda s, cat=cat_name: s.value_counts()[cat])
    transformed_df[f'{cat_name} Ratio'] = grouped_df['movement_state'].rolling(rolling_window_size, closed='both').apply(lambda s, cat=cat_name: s.value_counts(normalize=True)[cat])
```

For reproduction purposes just assume the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'movement_state': pd.Categorical(np.random.choice(['moving', 'standing', 'parking'], 20))}
grouped_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

rolling_window_size = 3
```

I want to do **rolling window operations** on my GroupBy Object. I am selecting the column `movement_state` beforehand. This column is categorical as shown below.

```py
grouped_df['movement_state'].dtypes

# Output
CategoricalDtype(categories=['moving', 'parking', 'standing'], ordered=False)
```

If I execute, I get these error messages:

```py
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
TypeError: cannot handle this type -> category
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'standing'
```

Inside this code snippet of `rolling.py` from the pandas source code I read that the data must be converted to `float64` before it can be processed by cython.

```py
def _prep_values(self, values: ArrayLike) -> np.ndarray:
    """Convert input to numpy arrays for Cython routines"""
    if needs_i8_conversion(values.dtype):
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f"ops for {type(self).__name__} for this "
            f"dtype {values.dtype} are not implemented"
        )
    else:
        # GH #12373 : rolling functions error on float32 data
        # make sure the data is coerced to float64
        try:
            if isinstance(values, ExtensionArray):
                values = values.to_numpy(np.float64, na_value=np.nan)
            else:
                values = ensure_float64(values)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as err:
            raise TypeError(f"cannot handle this type -> {values.dtype}") from err
```

#### My question to you

Is it possible to count the values of a categorical column in a pandas DataFrame using the `rolling` method as I tried to do?

A possible workaround a came up with is to just use the codes of the categorical column instead of the string values. But this way, `s.value_counts()[cat]` would raise a KeyError if the window I am looking at does not contain every possible value.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Which one? grouped_df?

Comment: grouped_df or any similar df that allows us to replicate this error

Comment: Added a reproduction example